# When are these integrals equal to each other?

Tags: integration

Suppose I have the integral:

$$ F = \int^1_0 \, \int_{x \in C} L[u + t(v -u)] (v - u) \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} t  $$

where $L$ is an operator of type $(\mathrm{R} \rightarrow \mathrm{R}) \rightarrow \mathrm{R} \rightarrow \mathrm{R}$ and $u$ and $v$ are arbitrary smooth functions of type $\mathrm{R} \rightarrow \mathrm{R}$.

What characteristics does the operator $L$ have to have such that the integral is equal to:

$$  \int^1_0 \, \int_{x \in C} L[T[t, u, v]] \frac{\mathrm{d} T[t, u, v]}{\mathrm{d} t} \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} t  $$

for other $T$ that provide a "path" between functions $u$ and $v$?

Comment: It's funny how you talk about the "type" of an operator: are you a Haskell or ML programmer?

Comment: In any case the Question will more likely get a substantive response if the characteristics of operator(?) $L$ can be stated in a more mathematical way.  Are we to understand that $u,v$ are smooth real functions, for example, and that $T$ is an arbitrary homotopy from $u$ to $v$ (in contrast to the linear homotopy entailed by the first integral)?